# sql server query results based on another resultset

Tags: sql-server, join, query-performance

My requirement is like below.

InstituteId is passed as parameter to my query, i need to get all the studentId's who are enrolled in any of the courses the institute is offering and they should be full time students..

There are chances that few users have registered but they are not enrolled in any courses, few users have enrolled on more than 1 course and in this case i need to display this user only once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.StudentId, f.[RegistrationId] from dbo.[Student] s
INNER JOIN dbo.FulltimeStudent f on s.StudentId = f.StundentId 
WHERE CourseId in (
SELECT CourseId from dbo.[Institute] WHERE InstituteId = @InstututeId 
)
```

I am seeing some performance lag with the above, I am seeing if there is any better approach to accomplish the above ?

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? Are the fields involved covered by indexes (StudentID, CourseId , InstituteId in all tables)? Changing the query won't improve performance if those fields aren't indexed

Comment: A SQL query isn't executed as is. The query engine converts it into an execution plan based on the underlying types, indexes *and* statistics. It may pick one execution plan if it expects an operation will return many rows and a very different one if it expects a lot of rows. The execution plan is what's actually getting executed and shows what may be wrong

Comment: `EXISTS`  often perform better if they are large result sets, because the execution can be stopped if 1 row matches, instead of IN. But like @PanagiotisKanavos said, [share](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) the actual execution plan. So we know what indexes are used / needed. You may also be suffering from parameter sniffing, but we can't tell at the moment.